# Date Filter Logic

Tags: sql, oracle, date

This is being used in a report and I cannot understand what they are trying to do here.

```
BETWEEN (((to_date(20230822, 'yyyymmdd') - DAY (to_date(20230822, 'yyyymmdd')) DAY + 1 DAY)) +(1) MONTH) 
    AND ((((to_date(20230822, 'yyyymmdd') - DAY (to_date(20230822, 'yyyymmdd')) DAY + 1 DAY) + 1 MONTH- 1 DAY)) +(1) MONTH)
```

I am trying to understand what period of time they are trying to get here.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above SQL snippet is very product specific.)

Answer (score 0):

Date functions are typically specific to one RDBMS.  This look partly like Oracle (`to_date()`) and partly SQL Server (`DAY()`), so that's confusing.

`to_date()` converts the 8-digit string to a date
`DAY()` returns the day of the month
`n DAY` is an interval
`n MONTH` is an interval

This appears to be...

between `first day of next month` and `last day of next month`

...where "this month" is where the given date falls.

So why not simplify it to say

```
where month(mydateval) = month(to_date(20230822, 'yyyymmdd') + 1 month)
```

Comment: I would still like to know what RDBMS is in use.  Haven't come across one that uses intervals that way, uses `DAY()` and uses `to_date()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Oracle based on the use of `to_date`, but either SQL server and Oracle, the following applies:

`DAY (to_date(20230822, 'yyyymmdd'))` returns an integer, representing the day of the Date.

Adding an integer to a Date adds to the `Day` part of the Date (To make it more clear, you should consider using `DateAdd`).

Hence, `(to_date(20230822, 'yyyymmdd') - DAY (to_date(20230822, 'yyyymmdd')` is the first day of the month. Adding one month to it will be the first day of the next month.

Adding `1 month - 1 day` to the first day of next month, is the last day of next month.

Hence, the range will be **The first day of next month** to **The last day of next month**.

Comment: This is Oracle, sorry for not using the right terms.  Appreciate the confirmation of Next Month Period!

Answer (score 0):

Its hard without knowing the dbms - is it Informix?
DAY usually returns the day of the month of the given date, so my guess would be:

BETWEEN

2023-08-22 - 22 Days + 1 Day + 1 Month = 2023-09-01

AND

2023-08-22 - 22 Days + 1 Day + 1 Month - 1 Day + 1 Month = 2023-09-30 (I assume!)

What it tries to do seems to be basically between begin of next month and end of next month. But I don't understand why you don't just test those two between arguments and check what they are evaluate to in your DBMS.

But to be honest - no idea what would be the result if you feed 2023-02-22 for example - someone would need to read the manual of your dbms about what would happen if 1 month gets added to 2023-02-28 - I could imagine it would be 2023-03-28 which looks like an unwanted result to me then?

Comment: This is from our Reporting team where I believe they are using incorrect date logic resulting in a loss of results.  This is helpful, I guessed it was the next month period which makes no sense for this application.  Appreciate the help!